# Why is my jquery post result disappearing?

Tags: jquery, post

I have a basic form that I would like to submit using ajax, without having to actually reload the page. This is the gist of the code:

```
<cfif cgi.request_method EQ "post">
    <cfdump var="#form#" />
    <cfabort />
</cfif>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#qsSearch').click(function(){
                    $.post(
                        '<cfoutput>#cgi.script_name#</cfoutput>',
                        $('#qsUserForm').serialize(),
                        function(data){
                            $('#results').html(data);
                        }
                    );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="qsUserForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name:</th><td><input id="qsFirstName" name="qsFirstName" type="text" /></td>
                    <th>Last Name:</th><td><input id="qsLastName" name="qsLastName" type="text" /></td>
                    <th>Username:</th><td><input id="qsUserName" name="qsUserName" type="text" /></td>
                    <th>Email:</th><td><input id="qsEmail" name="qsEmail" type="text" /></td>
                    <th>User ID:</th><td><input id="qsUserID" name="qsUserID" type="text" /></td>
                    <td><input id="qsSearch" name="qsSearch" type="submit" value="Search" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The form dump should be showing up in the "results" div. However, it doesn't.

Upon debugging with Firebug I noticed that the code *is* actually executing correctly, and the results are inserted into the results div - however, as soon as the post code exits, it disappears. If I put a breakpoint at the closing parenthesis for the post call, I can see the correct results in the results div - as soon as the code continues it disappears.

I have used code like this often enough before - what is wrong with this simple ajax post?

(I have tried replacing the search button click handler with the form submit handler, but it didn't change anything.)

Comment: Does it disappear like #results has no html or #results just gets hidden?

Comment: add a `return false;` in your click handler after the `$.post()`. Just a thought.

Comment: @nbrooks - the return false works as well - as it prevents it from continuing to the default submit code. If you post it as an answer I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your form is reloading

You should stop the form from submission using:

```
   $('#qsSearch').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('<cfoutput>#cgi.script_name#</cfoutput>', $('#qsUserForm').serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
});​
```

Comment: perfect! I thought it might be reloading but wasn't sure how to stop it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think I'm going to choose this method over the "return false" suggested by nbrooks in a comment as it seems to represent what I'm doing more clearly... Is either method "better" than the other?

Comment: @froadie `return false` is both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`. In your case, you need only `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` in your click handler after the `$.post()` to stop the default `onclick` behavior from proceeding when you're function is done being executed.